# Using custom functions in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like this

```
class Hourly extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div key={this.props.key} id={this.props.id} className="col-xs-3 text-center vcenter box parent">
        <div className="child">
          <div>{this._theDay(this.props.day)}</div>
          <div>{this.props.summary}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to use a custom function (_theDay) in the component which i use later in another component

Custom function:

```
_theDay(time) {
   moment.locale('en-gb');
   var dateTime = moment(time*1000).format('dddd');
   return dateTime;
  }
```

I call the component later with

```
        <Hourly
          key={hour.time}
          id={hour.time}
          day={hour.time}
          summary={hour.summary}
        />
```

However i get the error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.(…)`

When i just use `<div>{this.props.day}</div>;` everything works fine, but then i can't use my custom function

Comment: Tried to reproduce your issue, seems to work for me :-/ http://jsbin.com/wuqupehaqa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: hmmm i can see that... I tried to reorganize my code like in your example, which now tells me ` _this4._theDay is not a function`

Comment: Right, so I put the `_theDay` function inside the Hourly class, which I'm guessing doesn't work for you since you need to reuse that function elsewhere. If that's the case, don't use `this._theDay` when calling it, and put the function somewhere that's accessible to both components.

Comment: You're using `this._theDay`, but the function is not part of `this`, the component. You need to reference it differently. Perhaps try without the `this`.

Comment: Thanks @BFree - works as intended

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with React trying to update the DOM after props change. Try utilizing a key on the `<div/>` tied to the `props.day` to help it know that the children have changed.

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let day = this._theDay(this.props.day)
    return <div key={day}>{day}</div>;
  }
}
```

Here's the [documentation on reconciling the DOM.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html)

Comment: I stripped the component for simplicity which might have been a bad idea. I already have a key. I just updated my question